# Emulating Raspbian With Qemu in Arch linux

Tags: raspbian, emulation, qemu

I'm trying to emulate RaspbianOS on my Arch Linux host using `qemu-system-arm`. and I have run into some problems.

- The emulation works fine using the machine `versatilepb` but when invoking qemu-system-arm using `-M raspi2`, all I get is a black window.

  *What is the problem ? can I make it run using `raspi2` or even `virt` as the machine type?*
- Second, I used a Raspbian Stretch and the custom kernel was a jessie which I picked from [here](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel). When I replace the jessie custom kernel a stretch one, I get a black window with the message **guest has not initialized display yet**.

  *What is the role of the qemu-kernel and why does the qemu-stretch-kernel not work?*
- Finallly, to work properly the image has to be mounted in order to add these lines to `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-qemu.rules` .

  ```
  KERNEL=="sda", SYMLINK+="mmcblk0" 
  KERNEL=="sda?", SYMLINK+="mmcblk0p%n"
  KERNEL=="sda2", SYMLINK+="root"
  ```

  *what is their signification ? and why are they added ?*

Here is the command that I ran succesfully:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.26-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb \        
-no-reboot -drive format=raw,file=2018-10-09-raspbian-stretch-lite.img
```